# Rails: creating a drop down menu for a form

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

Would you know how to make a **pull down** or **drop down menu** for a form text field?

Currently, the user needs to to type in text "Rating" then submit the form. But ideally, they should select a rating of "Awesome" "Good" or "Meh" from a pull down, rather than be able to enter a custom text. Any advice in the right direction would be appreciated.

Thank you.

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for(@post) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">


    <%= f.input :Duration, required: true, autofocus: true %>
    <%= f.input :Rating %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit,  "Log it!" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to replace the line:

```
<%= f.input :Rating %>
```

with:

```
<%= f.select :Rating, options_for_select(["Awesome", "Good", "Meh"]) %>
```